# Nested list with dictionary as content

Tags: python

Hi how can I loop through lst2 below, and get the dictionary elements in lst1 if the elements are a match.

```
lst1 = [[(10, 70, {'a': 0.30}),
         (12, 82, {'b': 0.35})],
        [(11, 140, {'c': 0.54}),
         (99, 25, {'d': 0.57})]
       ]

lst2 = [[(10, 70), (32, 25),(12,82)],
        [(1598, 6009), (11,140), (33,66), (99,25)]
       ]
```

ie compare lst2 and if lst2 is in lst1 print the dictionary.

outcome should look like so:

```
outcome = [[{'a': 0.30}, {'b':0.35}], [{'c': 0.54}, {'d':0.57}]]
```

Thanks

Sorry an update on this one would be if lst1 is not nested ie

```
lst1 = [(10, 70, {'a': 0.30}),
        (12, 82, {'b': 0.35}),
        (11, 140, {'c': 0.54}),
        (99, 25, {'d': 0.57})
       ]

lst2 = [[(10, 70), (32, 25),(12,82)],
        [(1598, 6009), (11,140), (33,66), (99,25)]
       ]
```

such that the same outcome will be arrived at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten `lst1` and convert that to a dictionary with dictionary comprehension, so that the lookups will be faster. Once the dictionary is constructed, you just have to iterate `lst2` and if the element is a key in the dictionary, then get the corresponding dictionary value.

```
from itertools import chain
d = {(item[0], item[1]):item[2] for item in chain.from_iterable(lst1)}
print d
# {(12,82):{'b':0.3}, (10,70):{'a':0.3}, (11,140):{'c':0.54}, (99,25):{'d':0.57}}
print [[d[item] for item in items if item in d] for items in lst2]
# [[{'a': 0.3}, {'b': 0.3}], [{'c': 0.54}, {'d': 0.57}]]
```

If the input is not nested, like in the updated question, you don't need chaining. You can simply do

```
d = {(item[0], item[1]):item[2] for item in lst1}
```

Comment: `    d = { (item[0], item[1]) : item[2] for item in chain.from_iterable(lst1) }
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I run the code in Python 2.6, when i run it in Python 2.7, it is ok.

Comment: @BlackMamba Oh yeah, dictionary comprehension is not introduced in Python 2.6. Try this `d = dict(((item[0], item[1]), item[2]) for item in lst1)`

Answer (score 1):

For each pair, create a `dict` for the elements from `lst1` (for performance) and then check for each of the elements from `lst2`.

```
outcome = []
for lst_a, lst_b in zip(lst1, lst2):
    lookup = {a[:-1]:a[-1] for a in lst_a}
    outcome.append([lookup[b] for b in lst_b if b in lookup])
print outcome
```